# get jmx attributes with jolokia telegraf

Tags: jmx, telegraf, jolokia

I have a JAVA application which I want to monitor its JMX attributes using [`telegraf`](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) tool.

The tool provides `jolikia` plugin to monitor JMX attributes. I have added following dependencies to my app's `pom.xml` file regarding `Maven` section of [Jolokia documentation](https://jolokia.org/download.html):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
    <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
    <artifactId>jolokia-client-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` file:

```
[[inputs.jolokia]]

   context = "/jolokia/"
   [[inputs.jolokia.servers]]
       name = "wr-core"
       host = "192.168.100.175"
       port = "1998"

   [[inputs.jolokia.metrics]]
       name = "send_success"
       mbean  = "wr-core:type=monitor,name=execution"
       attribute = "MessageSendSuccessCount"
```

The application is up in the provided IP/port (I can connect to it with `jconsole`). The application has a monitoring section which its object name (as shown in `jconsole`) is `wr-core:type=monitor,name=execution` and has the attribute `MessageSendSuccessCount`. But when I start `telegraf` service, following error occurs:

```
Jan 14 14:30:32 ZiZi telegraf[17258]: 2018-01-14T11:00:32Z E! Error in plugin [inputs.jolokia]: error performing request: Error decoding JSON response: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value:
```

Note that `1998` is my app's jmx port. I also tried using `8778` which is `jolokia-agent` port; got:

```
Jan 14 14:40:03 ZiZi telegraf[9150]: 2018-01-14T11:10:03Z E! Error in plugin [inputs.jolokia]: error performing request: Post http://192.168.100.175:8778/jolokia/: dial tcp 192.168.100.175:8778: getsockopt: connection refused
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have checked my `CLASSPATH` and both `jolokia-client` and `jolokia-core` were listed: `../lib/jolokia-client-java-1.3.7.jar:../lib/jolokia-core-1.3.7.jar`.

**EDIT 2:**

I have put following lines into my app's execution file:

```
JOLOKIA_OPTS=-javaagent:$LIB_PATH/jolokia-core-java-1.3.7.jar=port=8778,host=0.0.0.0

JAVA_OPTS="-mx4096M $JAVA_OPTS $JACOCO_OPTS $JOLOKIA_OPTS"
```

But when I run the file, I get this error (even though `../lib/jolokia-core-java-1.3.7.jar` has been listed in the `CLASSPATH`):

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ../lib/jolokia-core-java-1.3.7.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

I have skipped `maven` solution and tried the `javaagent` approach, but I had misunderstood the usage of `javaagent` previously; I should address [jolokia jvm agent](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jolokia/jolokia-jvm/1.3.7/jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar) ([this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-get-metrics-from-a-java-application-inside) helped):

```
JOLOKIA_OPTS=-javaagent:/root/jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar=port=8778,host=0.0.0.0
JAVA_OPTS="-mx4096M $JAVA_OPTS $JACOCO_OPTS $JOLOKIA_OPTS"
```

Now, my app starts with this log (successfully):

```
I> No access restrictor found, access to any MBean is allowed
Jolokia: Agent started with URL http://192.168.100.175:8778/jolokia/
```

In the other side there is no error in the `telegraf` console for `jolokia` anymore.

All the observation are implying the jolokia jvm library has been started and works successfully.

I have also found [jolokia jmx documentation](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/jmx.html) for using it as dependencies in the project; but since I'm not a JAVA expert (I'm testing the app), I prefer to currently use the `javaagent` approach and leave it for future study/experience. BTW, it may help the others.

**EDIT 1:**

I have found and deployed `jolokia jvm agent` using its [spring support](https://jolokia.org/reference/html/jmx.html#jvm-spring).

Configuring it in the `spring` XML file, I can now have `jolokia jvm agent` start listening at my app's startup.